# Hybrid auth 2.1.2 doesnt log in

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, hybridauth

I downloaded [hybrid auth version 2.1.2](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) and tried setting it up by following these instructions.

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/459/integrating-hybridauth-directly-into-yii-without-an-extension/

But when I click on this link on my login page

```
<a href="login?provider=facebook">facebook</a>
```

all it does it redirects to this link. And I don't get any facebook popup whats so ever.

```
http://localhost/dev/?hauth.start=Facebook&hauth.time=1387565904
```

In my site controller I edited my **actionLogin()** to this and added **actionSocialLogin()** too. Any idea why this doesn't work?

```
/**
     * Displays the login page
     */
    public function actionLogin() 
    {
        if (!isset($_GET['provider']))
        {
            if(app()->user->isGuest()){
                    $model = new LoginForm;

                    // if it is ajax validation request
                    if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'login-form') {
                        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
                        app()->end();
                    }

                    // collect user input data
                    if (isset($_POST['LoginForm'])) {
                        $model->attributes = $_POST['LoginForm'];
                        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
                        if ($model->validate() && $model->login()) {
                            $user = app()->user->getUser();
                            User::model()->updateByPk($user->id, array('last_login' => new CDbExpression('NOW()')));
                            if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
                                echo app()->user->getHomeUrl();
                                app()->end();
                            } else {
                                $this->redirect(app()->user->returnUrl);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
                                echo "bad";
                                app()->end();
                            } else {
                                app()->user->setFlash('error', 'Login failed. Please try again.');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // display the login form
                    $this->render('login', array('model' => $model));
                } else {
                    $this->redirect(array('/user/update', 'id' => app()->user->id));
                }
            }
            else {
                try
                {
                    //Yii::import('ext.components.HybridAuthIdentity');
                    $haComp = new HybridAuthIdentity();
                    if (!$haComp->validateProviderName($_GET['provider']))
                        throw new CHttpException ('500', 'Invalid Action. Please try again.');

                    $haComp->adapter = $haComp->hybridAuth->authenticate($_GET['provider']);
                    $haComp->userProfile = $haComp->adapter->getUserProfile();

                    $haComp->login();
                    $this->redirect('http://localhost/dev/');  //redirect to the user logged in section..

                    $haComp->processLogin();  //further action based on successful login or re-direct user to the required url
                }
                catch (Exception $e)
                {
                    //process error message as required or as mentioned in the HybridAuth 'Simple Sign-in script' documentation
                    $this->redirect('/site/index');
                    return;
                }       
            }

    }

public function actionSocialLogin()
    {
        //Yii::import('ext.components.HybridAuthIdentity');
        $path = Yii::getPathOfAlias('ext.HybridAuth');

        require_once $path . '/hybridauth-' . HybridAuthIdentity::VERSION . '/hybridauth/index.php';

    }

    /**
     * Logs out the current user and redirect to homepage.
     */
    public function actionLogout() {
        app()->user->logout();
        $this->redirect(app()->homeUrl);
    }
```

and i have this in my **HybridAuthIdentity class**

```
public function login()
    {
        $this->username = $this->userProfile->email;  //CUserIdentity
        Yii::app()->user->login($this, 0);
    }

    public function authenticate() 
    {
        return true;
    }
```

also what do i add to write data into this DB?

```
`userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `loginProvider` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `loginProviderIdentifier` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: Have you configured the base url for hybridauth? Because it seems like it's not redirecting to the hybridauth endpoint (which is required for it to do something).

Comment: @towr ok i changed my base_url to `"base_url" => Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('/').'/site/socialLogin',` and now it redirects to `http://localhost/hero/#_=_` and still no change. my nav bar still says "login". any ideas?

Comment: @towr any idea? anyone?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Yii, so that limits my usefulness somewhat. I do see your actionLogin is quite different from the instructions you're basing it on. Have you tried getting that version working as-is? It might also be worth checking if the browser is doing multiple sequential redirects (it might be going wrong at another point than it seems), and checking whether the route to the hybrid-auth endpoint is working by `die()`ing there. You can also inspect the session-data to see if hybridauth is setting data there as it should (it adds `HA::CONFIG` and a few other keys).